# How to change data inside table django?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been creating clone of Twitter. User can register, login, write tweets. Tweet modal is here:

```
class TweetModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}: {self.text[0:15]}'
```

Once user changes his/her username, I want to change username in the tweets they write also.
How can I handle this? Thank you.

Comment: And why do you store the users username in other tables? The foreign key alone is enough.

Comment: You can create a unique id for each users in a class named "Profile" with username, profile picture and the ID, and then make a filed in your tweetModel with the id of the user and then display the info in the html by showing the username of the user with the user id of the tweet.

Comment: Because I need to render owner of each tweet in frontend. [Abdul Aziz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the username in `TweetModel`. You can have access to the username like this:

```
tweet = TweetModel.objects.get(pk=1).owner.username
```

`owner` is a `ForeignKey` which means it stores the user id and `.owner` means to find the user with this id and `.username` means to return the `username` field for that user.

Now you're directly accessing the `User` table so any changes will be there.

Comment: But I need owner of each tweet. I need to render them in frontend. How can I know without storing owner?[bruh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8069748/navid-zarepak)

Comment: `tweet.owner` is the owner and you can access it in a template too. Basically, it returns an instance of the model that you specified as `ForeignKey` which in this case is `User`.

Comment: But my frontend(react) is seperate from django. I am getting data via REST API. [Navid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8069748/navid-zarepak)

Comment: You can also serialize relations in DRF in case you're using it for your API. And if you're doing it manually, then you can do the same with `owner`. `owner` is an instance of a model just like any other model instance and you can do whatever you want with it.